# Onchange field data is becoming [object object] react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a fields in which I need to get data from object and show them as comma separated like this

```
const data = [{id: 1, name: "dine", restaurant: 2}, {id: 2, name: "pick", restaurant: 2}];
const combined = data.map(el => el.name).join(",");
```

and showed it in form like this

```
<div className='form-group text-left'>
  <InputField value={combined} 
  onChange={e => changeingredientdata(e)}
```

/>
    
Now when I change field data and try to add a new word to it change data to [object object]  my onchange function is like

```
function changeingredientdata(e) {
    setcombinedingredients({ ...combinedingredients,
      [e.target.name] : [e.target.value]
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a list as value, replace

```
[e.target.name] : [e.target.value]
```

with

```
[e.target.name] : e.target.value
```

Comment: Share the implementation of `setcombinedingredients`